# POST request fails with 'Forbidden' using mail REST API (Exchange Office 365)

Tags: office365

i tried making post request to mail api https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/sendmail
with access token and it is throwing an error saying that it is forbidden request.i made an post request as follows:
POST https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/sendmail
Authorization:Bearer 'access token'
and in body:

```
{
    "Message": {
        "Subject": "Meetforlunch?",
        "Body": {
            "ContentType": "Text",
            "Content": "Thenewcafeteriaisopen."
        },
        "ToRecipients": [
            {
                "EmailAddress": {
                    "Address": "admin@xtreamit.onmicrosoft.com"
                }
            }
        ],
        "Attachments": [
            {
                "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.OutlookServices.FileAttachment",
                "Name": "menu.txt",
                "ContentBytes": "bWFjIGFuZCBjaGVlc2UgdG9kYXk="
            }
        ]
    },
    "SaveToSentItems": "false"
}
```

can some one suggest what am i missing or their is some permission which has to be assigned while sending post request.it is working perfect when i make get request

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to mind is that you don't have the permission to send mail selected in your app registration. If you copy your access token and paste it into http://jwt.calebb.net/, do you see Mail.Send in the scp claim?

**EDIT:**
Also, if you're sending HTTP requests manually, make sure you are setting the Content-Type header to "application/json".

Comment: i have given following permissions Calendars.Write Mail.Read Mail.Send Mail.Write